# Open Source GIS tools for using LiDAR to estimate storage behind dams/culvert

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, lidar, modelling, data-storage

Can you recommend an open source GIS tools for modeling the water impounded on the upstream side of a dam using LiDAR data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also consider using GRASS-GIS to import and process your LiDAR data. There is detailed information provided [on the GRASS Wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR) and an example of a DEM created and visualised included below.

In order to estimate the storage behind a dam, you might be able to use the GRASS GIS module [r.lake](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.lake.html). However, you may need to modify the program in order to model the height and location of the dam itself.

[image: r.in.lidar]

Answer (score 2):

You have a LiDAR derived surface model and you want to calculate the volume of water that would be behind a theoretical dam?  If so, have a look at this link http://www.bc-consult.com/tut/QGIS-volumes.php

If the dam is already in place and filled with water and you want to calculate that volume of water-you will need to collect bathymetry data.